Log4j Additional Logging and Error upgrading from version 2.23.0 to 2.23.1
While upgrading from the dependencies for log4j between version 2.23.0. and 2.23.1 we are encountering additional logging and seeing errors in the log.
Additional Trace Logging
Log4j2-TF-3-Scheduled-1 TRACE WatchRunnable run triggered.
Log4j2-TF-3-Scheduled-1 TRACE WatchRunnable run ended.

In the application we have Java properties set to not allow these messages:
-Dlog4j2.debug=false
-Dlog4j2.isThreadContextMapInheritable=true
-Dlog4j2.statusLoggerLevel=off

The messages do not appear if changing the dependencies back to version 2.23.0.
Errors in Logs
We are also seeing errors in the log referring to JndiLookup class is missing.
Default Executor-thread-7 INFO Plugin [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup] could not be loaded due to missing classes. 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup at
 server.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:578) at
 server.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.loadClass(AppClassLoader.java:553) at 
 java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.decodeCacheFiles(PluginRegistry.java:180) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromMainClassLoader(PluginRegistry.java:117) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:137) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:81) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:109) at
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:136) at
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:76) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:263) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:222) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:140) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:149) at 
 org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:46) at
 org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:197) at
 org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:611)

Even though we do not use Jndi lookup and configure the messages with {nolookups}.  The errors do not appear if changing the dependencies back to version 2.23.0.
Dependencies
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.23.1</version>
</dependency>

log4j.xml configuration
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPattern">%date{ISO8601_OFFSET_DATE_TIME_HHMM} [%-5level] [%logger] %message{nolookups}%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <!-- Simple console logger -->
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="myAppender"
                     fileName=app.log"
                     filePattern=app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${logPattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy />
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" />
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy min="1" max="1">
                <Delete maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="app-*.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="1d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="myAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>

Are these both bugs or is there additional configuration or dependencies necessary?

Use code format for logs, not quote format. Quote is for human text, not logs and other pre formatted text. Quote breaks the existing format of the log, makes it very hard to read and gets in the way of trying to copy text for investigation.

Please share your log4j2 configuration.

@aled - thank you for the recommendations, I have adjusted the log and added the log4j2.xml configuration for reference.

Why are you using a version so old? The latest version at this time is 2.23.1: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/release-notes.html

@aled I apologize I missed typed the version as we are going from 2.23.0 to 2.23.1 and not 2.3.x.  I adjusted the question.

Do you modify somehow log4j-core before deployment? Is the JndiLookup class missing? What is the value of log4j2.defaultStatusLevel? Does the problem disappear if you set status="WARN" on the <Configuration> element?

@PiotrP.Karwasz - no modification to log4j-core.  According to the jar file the lookup exists in the proper package.  I do not set log4j2.defaultStatusLevel therefore it would be the default value.  Changing the overall status has no effect.

When you put a breakpoint to PluginRegistry.java:180 while using 2.23.0, can you observe that JndiLookup gets loaded successfully?
